# TextMeshPro Text colors reset when moved

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been struggling with this issue for a while now-
Essentially I have a TMP_Text object. Then (like in TMP example 23), I am setting the character's vertices colors to a specified color. However, when I move the TMP_Text object, all of the character's colors get reset. 
Here is the relevant code that sets character color as well as a [video displaying this behavior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Xa2oja8LFA):

```
    private void ChangeColor(int i, Color32 c)
    //changes color of the letter that is @ specific index to a color32
    //this is getting called elsewhere in the script
    {
        int materialIndex = tf_.characterInfo[i].materialReferenceIndex;//get characters material index
        cols = tf_.meshInfo[materialIndex].colors32;//get its colors
        int vertexIndex = tf_.characterInfo[i].vertexIndex;//get its vertex index

        cols[vertexIndex + 0] = c;//set vertex color to C
        cols[vertexIndex + 1] = c;// ^
        cols[vertexIndex + 2] = c;// ^
        cols[vertexIndex + 3] = c;// ^

        ms_.UpdateVertexData(TMP_VertexDataUpdateFlags.Colors32);
        //update the vertex data to render the new colors
    }

    public void scrollContent()//this moves the TMP_Text object
    {
        sr.verticalNormalizedPosition = 0;//scroll the rect to the bottom
        //performing this^ movement changes the objects position, thus resetting all the colors.
    }
}
```

Comment: I would put my money that when you move the scroll rect, it calls a redraw to TextMeshPro, which in turn overwrites the vertex colors you entered with the ones it has stored. I think that if you redo all the vertex colors from the start after you move the text, this should work fine.